# Interpretation of Hartigans' dip test

Tags: r, distributions

I would like to find a way to quantify the intensity of bimodality of some distributions I got empirically. 
From what I read, there is still some debate about the way to quantify bimodality. I chose to use Hartigans' dip test which seems to be the only one available on R (original paper : http://www.stat.washington.edu/wxs/Stat593-s03/Literature/hartigan85a.pdf). Hartigans' dip test is defined as : *"The dip test measures multimodality in a sample by the maximum difference, over all sample points, between the empirical distribution function, and the unimodal distribution function that minimizes that maximum difference"*.

I would like to understand completely how I should interpret this statistics before using it. I was expecting that the dip test would increase if the distribution is multimodal (as it is defined as "the maximum difference from the unimodal distribution"). **But** : you can read in the wikipedia page about multimodal distribution that *"Values less than 0.05 indicate significant bimodality and values greater than 0.05 but less than 0.10 suggest bimodality with marginal significance."*. Such statement comes from this [paper](http://psych.nyu.edu/freemanlab/pubs/2012_BRM.pdf) (Fig. 2). According this paper, the dip test index is close to 0 when the distribution is bimodal. It confuses me.

To interpret correctly the Hartigans' dip test I constructed some distributions (the original code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530010/how-to-simulate-bimodal-distribution-in-r)) and I increased the value of exp(mu2) (called 'Intensity of bimodularity' from now on *- Edit : I should have called it 'Intensity of bimodality'*) to get bimodality. In the first graph, you can see some example of distributions. Then I estimated the diptest index (second graph) and the p value (third graphe) associated (package *diptest*) to those different simulated distributions. The R code used is at the end of my post.

**What I show here is that the dip test index is high and the Pvalue is low when the distibutions are bimodal.** Which is contrary to what you can read on the internet.

I am no expert in statistics, so that I barely understood Hartigans' paper. I would like to get some comments about the right way we should interpret Hartigans' dip test. Am I wrong somewhere ?

Thank you all.
Regards,

T.A.

Example of distribution simulated :
[image: Example of distribution simulated]

Hartigan's dip test index associated :
[image]

Hartigan's dip test p.value associated :
[image]

```
library(diptest)
library(ggplot2)


# CONSTANT PARAMETERS
sig1 <- log(3)
sig2 <- log(3)
cpct <- 0.5
N=1000

#CREATING BIMOD DISTRIBUTION
bimodalDistFunc <- function (n,cpct, mu1, mu2, sig1, sig2) {
  y0 <- rlnorm(n,mean=mu1, sd = sig1)
  y1 <- rlnorm(n,mean=mu2, sd = sig2)

  flag <- rbinom(n,size=1,prob=cpct)
  y <- y0*(1 - flag) + y1*flag 
}

#DIP TEST
DIP_TEST <- function(bimodalData) {
  TEST <- dip.test(bimodalData)
  return(TEST$statistic[[1]])   # return(TEST$p.value[[1]])    to get the p value
}
DIP_TEST(bimodalData)


# SIMULATION
exp_mu1 = 1
max_exp_mu2 = 100
intervStep = 100
repPerInt = 10

# single distibutions
expMu2Value <- c()
bimodalData <- c()
mu1 <- log(exp_mu1)   
mu2 <- log(exp_mu1)
bimodalData <- c(bimodalData,log(bimodalDistFunc(n=N,cpct,mu1,mu2, sig1,sig2)))
expMu2Value <- c(expMu2Value,rep(exp_mu1,length(log(bimodalDistFunc(n=N,cpct,mu1,mu2, sig1,sig2)))))

mu1 <- log(exp_mu1)   
mu2 <- log(max_exp_mu2)
bimodalData <- c(bimodalData,log(bimodalDistFunc(n=N,cpct,mu1,mu2, sig1,sig2)))
expMu2Value <- c(expMu2Value,rep(max_exp_mu2,length(log(bimodalDistFunc(n=N,cpct,mu1,mu2, sig1,sig2)))))

mu1 <- log(exp_mu1)   
mu2 <- log(trunc((max_exp_mu2-exp_mu1)/2+1))
bimodalData <- c(bimodalData,log(bimodalDistFunc(n=N,cpct,mu1,mu2, sig1,sig2)))
expMu2Value <- c(expMu2Value,rep(trunc((max_exp_mu2-exp_mu1)/2+1),length(log(bimodalDistFunc(n=N,cpct,mu1,mu2, sig1,sig2)))))

tableExamples <- data.frame(expMu2Value,bimodalData)
tableExamples$expMu2Value <- as.factor(tableExamples$expMu2Value)
ExamplePlot <- ggplot(tableExamples)+
  geom_histogram(aes(bimodalData),color='white')+
  ylab("Count")+
  xlab("")+
  facet_wrap(~expMu2Value)+
  ggtitle("Intensity of bimodularity")

# calculation of the dip test index
exp_mu2Int = seq(from=exp_mu1,to=max_exp_mu2,length.out=intervStep)
expmu2Vec = c()
dipStat = c()
testDone = c()
for(exp_mu2 in exp_mu2Int){
  mu1 <- log(exp_mu1)   
  mu2 <- log(exp_mu2)
  for(rep in 1:repPerInt){
    bimodalData <- log(bimodalDistFunc(n=N,cpct,mu1,mu2, sig1,sig2))
    diptestone = DIP_TEST(bimodalData)
    expmu2Vec = c(expmu2Vec,exp_mu2)
    dipStat = c(dipStat,diptestone)
    testDone = c(testDone,"diptest")
  }
}
table = data.frame(expmu2Vec,dipStat,testDone)

IndexPlot <- ggplot(table)+
  geom_point(aes(expmu2Vec,dipStat,color=testDone))+
  ylab("Index")+
  xlab("Intensity of Bimodularity")+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Test")

ExamplePlot
IndexPlot
```

Comment: Very thorough question work up about a topic that is arcane by any statistician's standards. The obvious first questions, before one even gets into *interpretation* is, "Why do you need this test? What information is it intended to communicate?" Can provide some additional context for the motivations that have led you to the much, much further downstream issue of the interpretation of the results from the "dip test?" In other words, other than it's convenience wrt R programming, what path of logic has led you to the "dip test" in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for you answer, Mike. I'm working on a theoretical model in evolutionary biology and I am carrying out a sensitivity analysis. In particular, I observe that varying some parameters modify the distribution of a output variable from unimodal to bimodal (which is actually very interesting). That's why I'm looking for a simple statistics to describe the multimodularity of a distribution. It would allow me to focus the sensitivity analysis on the multimodularity.

Comment: I found out that the dip test could be easily calculated in R and that it could quantify the deviance from a unimodal distribution. Of course, I would be really interested by any other statistics describing the multimodularity of a distribution.

Comment: Hmmm...fitting a few humble polynomials could amount to a "poor man's" approach to dealing with the curvilinearity you're observing and might be more readily deployed and interpreted than Hartigan's test. You don't say whether your issues include dealing with any growth functions. For instance, in human development, there are several well-known "bumps" in the growth trajectory at distinct points of the life cycle. Nonparametric models have been found to better fit and approximate these nonlinearities than parametric models.

Comment: **Terminology** As in your quotations, common, indeed standard terms are _unimodal_, _bimodal_, _multimodal_ (adjectives for  having one, two, many modes) and _unimodality_, _bimodality_, _multimodality_ (nouns). Less common are _trimodal_, _trimodality_ and perhaps others, but naturally it is much simpler to say that there appear to be 2 or 4 or 7 modes or whatever the number is. That said, I can't see any point to using less standard words _bimodularity_, _multimodularity_ and so forth. Are they used in any literature _in this sense_? (Being modular is **not** the question here.)

Comment: The original paper was by two people named Hartigan, who happen to be husband and wife. Hartigans' dip test is a good name given that.

Comment: On the statistical issues: As said, the dip test takes unimodality as a reference. I don't think departures from it can be interpreted in terms of the number of modes just from the P-value. I've found it immensely more useful to interpret number of modes with a combination of density estimation and substantive interpretation.

Comment: @Mike Hunter The test here refers **only** to possible bumps in, or on,  continuous  probability distributions. Bumps on growth curves etc. indeed often require or deserve different methodology, but I don't think that fitting polynomials to density functions is general enough to be an alternative here, if only because it would be hard to guarantee non-negative densities. Similar comments would apply to distribution or quantile functions.

Comment: @NickCox  Ok, developing that theme of density functions, have you explored the large literature on multivariate densities? A good overview is David Scott's *Multivariate Density Estimation* a new edition of which just came out in March 2015.

Comment: @Mike Hunter Thanks; I know of that literature and have contributed; that is why I mentioned density estimation as a good way forward.

Comment: @NickCox  You don't need my help...Scott's the best mind working in the field though.

Comment: Thank you for your comments (both on the terminology and the statistical content). In my study, I do not deal with any growth functions and I am actually not interested in counting the number of 'bumps' (from what I observed it is either unimodal or bimodal).

Comment: As I am not familiar with the theme of density functions I quite understood your last comments... 
So my questions at this point are : "Is the dip test a statistics suited to my situation" (I think so as I would like to quantify the 'deviance' from the unimodal distribution). If so : "How should it be interpreted ?". If not : "what alternative statistics would be suited ? Do you have any references to help me to code it in R ?"

Comment: You are interested in counting modes, one or two. (The term _bump_ is sometimes just informal and sometimes formal, but set that aside.) There is no need for you to write code for density estimation in R or for that matter in any well-known statistical environment, as it's well supported already. But note that its main thrust is not significance testing and also that coding questions strict sense are off-topic here.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mr. Freeman (author of the [paper](http://psych.nyu.edu/freemanlab/pubs/2012_BRM.pdf) I told you about) told me that he was actually looking only at the Pvalue of the dip test. This confusion comes from his sentence :
*"HDS values range from 0 to 1 with values less than .05 indicating significant bimodality, and values greater than .05 but less than .10 suggesting bimodality with marginal significance"*. HDS values corresponds to the Pvalue, and not the dip test statistics. It was unclear in the paper.

My analysis is good : the dip test statistics increases when the distribution is deviant from a unimodal distribution.

Bimodality test and Silverman's test can also be computed easily in R and do the job well.

Comment: Please register & merge your accounts. You can find information about how to do this in the **My Account** section of our [help].

Comment: The link to the paper is missing? Also, indicating its title, rather than a private message like "the paper I told you about", might be more useful ;-)